# SQL Query for aggregation/concatenation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table like this:

```
ID    Name
----------
1   john
1   molly
2   greg
2   sean
1   holly
2   mill
```

What should the SQL Query be to aggregate results like the following:

```
ID  Name
-------------
1   john/molly/holly
2   greg/sean/mill
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: The [STUFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) function simply removes the leading / from the string returned.

```
SELECT t1.id, 
       STUFF((SELECT '/' + t2.name
                FROM YourTable t2
                WHERE t1.id = t2.id
                ORDER BY t2.name
                FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS Name
    FROM YourTable t1
    GROUP BY t1.id
```