# How to stuff duplicate records in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simulating group_concat MySQL function in MS SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005)
>   [SQL Query for aggregation/concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896239/sql-query-for-aggregation-concatenation)

I am trying to use the stuff function in SQL server to stuff certain info. Here is the example:

```
Money     Age    Gender
860       9          F
860       15         M
860       15         M
860       16         M
860       16         F
```

I would like to stuff the Age and Gender column so that only one record will display as following:

```
Money   Age                 Gender
860     9, 15, 15, 16, 16   F, M, M, M, F
```

Please note, I would like to keep the two 15s and three M in the Age and Gender respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easier to do using a FOR XML rather than stuff.  Keep in mind that the FORM XML clause can be tricked to generate a comma seperated list (CSV).

The example below should do exactly what you are asking for.

```
CREATE TABLE moneyagegender 
( 
 [Money]  INT, 
 [Age]    INT, 
 [Gender] VARCHAR(2) 
); 

INSERT INTO moneyagegender 
VALUES      (860, 9, 'F'), 
        (860, 15, 'M'), 
        (860, 15, 'M'), 
        (860, 16, 'M'), 
        (860, 16, 'F'); 

SELECT mag.money, 
   (SELECT Substring((SELECT ', ' + CAST(m2.age AS VARCHAR(1024)) 
                      FROM   moneyagegender m2 
                      WHERE  m2.money = mag.money 
                      ORDER  BY m2.age 
                      FOR XML PATH('')), 3, 10000000) AS list) AS ages, 
   (SELECT Substring((SELECT ', ' + m3.gender 
                      FROM   moneyagegender m3 
                      WHERE  m3.money = mag.money 
                      ORDER  BY m3.age 
                      FOR XML PATH('')), 3, 10000000) AS list) AS genders 
FROM   moneyagegender mag 
GROUP  BY mag.money;
```

and here is the output.

```
Money       Ages                 Genders
----------- -------------------- -----------------
860         9, 15, 15, 16, 16    F, M, M, M, F
(1 row(s) affected)
```

I hope this helps.

If you need more details, I have a blog posting from last year that explains this.
http://stevestedman.com/2011/10/converting-part-of-a-result-set-to-a-comma-separated-list/

Comment: In the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896239/sql-query-for-aggregation-concatenation) I linked to [Joe Stefanelli](http://stackoverflow.com/users/341251/joe-stefanelli) explains that `STUFF` is only used to remove the unwanted first separator (in a much cleaner way than `substring(,3,10000000)`.

Comment: @ Steve and GSerg, both answers worked perfectly. Many thanks!

Comment: @ Steve, suppose i have more than one columns (in this case let say date_time, location, Store and then Money column which in was the orginal from this script, would it work?

Comment: Yes, this way of doing things will work for one or more columns.  In the example I showed 2 subqueries to pull the data for 2 columns, but there is not reason that you couldn't do the same thing for many columns.

Comment: @SteveStedman is there anyway to remove the duplicates? like **15**,  **M** and **F**

Comment: YES, just add DISTINCT  to the SELECT statements inside the substrings.